# Selenium Python bindings: dealing with inconsistent modals

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to fill out a form on a website that has different versions depending on language, location, etc. I am using the same firefox profile for every request, and the previously selected information is stored locally in cookies, so after choosing a setting the first time, the modal doesn't appear for a while. **However**: it seems to inconsistently appear, taking focus away from the form and causing an `ElementNotInteractableException.`

To add more difficulty, the modal will often appear some time after the page has loaded. For example, the first field will already be filled out, and then it appears.

My question is, what is the best way to handle this modal? Can I catch the exception cause by its appearance, check for the presence of the modal, and then continue populating the form fields? Or is there a better solution?

Thanks for any help.

The code I have tried so far:

```
url = "https://www.aircanada.com/ca/en/aco/home.html"
control_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/path/to/my/profile')
browser_control = webdriver.Firefox(control_profile)

browser_control.get(url)

# To deal with the modal, but obviously fails when it is not present
browser_control.find_element_by_id('enCAEdition').click()

# two text fields I tried to fill out, as a sanity check
departure = browser_control.find_element_by_id('origin_focus_0')
departure.send_keys("my departure location")
departure.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

destination = browser_control.find_element_by_id('destination_label_0')
destination.send_keys("my destination")
destination.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Can you share page `URL` and code you've tried so far?

Comment: sure, here's the page: https://www.aircanada.com/ca/en/aco/home.html , I will append my code to the question

Comment: I've included two simple examples of trying to fill in some text fields, which fail due to the modal. Often the first field is filled out correctly, but fails just before sending a return. Otherwise, it fails when the modal fails to appear, and the first button element is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait some time until modal appears, close it and handle form:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

url = "https://www.aircanada.com/ca/en/aco/home.html"
control_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/path/to/my/profile')
browser_control = webdriver.Firefox(control_profile)

browser_control.get(url)

# Wait up to 10 seconds until modal appears to close it
try:
    wait(browser_control, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(('xpath', '//button[text()="Confirm | Confirmer"]'))).click()
# If modal didn't appear- just continue
except TimeoutException:
    pass

departure = browser_control.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="FROM"]')
browser_control.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("class","glyph-input glyph-left-input form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched");', departure)
departure.send_keys("Berlin")
wait(browser_control, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(("xpath", "(//div[@class='location-primary']/span)[1]")))
departure.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

destination = browser_control.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="TO"]')
browser_control.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("class","glyph-input glyph-left-input form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched");', destination)
destination.send_keys("Oslo")
wait(browser_control, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(("xpath", "(//div[@class='location-primary']/span)[4]")))
destination.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, worked great so I'm marking it as accepted. Although, I'm starting to think my problem is actually when the return is sent. When I physically type in a location, and press enter, the first element on the dropdown is automatically selected. But for some reason, it seems to fail in the script. Would you have any insight into solving that?

Comment: I just noticed that, when in focus, this particular div gets an added class "hidden," but with a lack of actual input elements I'm not sure what else to use

Comment: Thanks again for the quick answer. I tried a different approach, by sending keys, waiting for the dropdown to appear, then selecting and clicking the first element by its xpath. It seems to work so far, but if I run into trouble I'll try your solution